# Logic: difference between "interpretation" and "structure"

Tags: logic

I never quite got the difference between an "interpretation" and a "structure" in logic. To me, they always sound like the same thing: a function from elements of a language to a particular universe.

The "[Structure (mathematical logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic))" page on Wikipedia says:

> Formally, a structure can be defined as a triple $\mathcal A=(A, \sigma, I)$ consisting of a domain $A$, a signature $\sigma$, and an
>   interpretation function $I$ that indicates how the signature is to be
>   interpreted on the domain.

From that, an interpretation is merely a component of a structure. However, I would say the function $I$ necessarily contains information about its domain (as in "function domain", a different sense of "domain" as used in the quote above) and its codomain, which must be $\sigma$ and $A$, respectively, so there is always a one-to-one correspondence between structures and interpretations.

Can anyone clarify what I am missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a technicality, but the intepretation doesn't contain all the information needed to recover the structure in all cases: consider the signature $\sigma = (R^2)$ with a single binary relation symbol $R$ and the structure $(A, \sigma, I)$ where $A = \Bbb{N}$ and $I(R) = \emptyset$. I.e., we've taken the universe of the structure to be the natural numbers and interpreted $R$ as the relation which is always false. You can't recover $A$ or $\sigma$ from $I$ (which doesn't tell you that $A = \Bbb{N}$ or that $R$ is a binary relation).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I was assuming that a function always "carries" information about its domain and codomain, even if it is a function like the one you defined. By talking about functions "carrying" information, I am perhaps giving away my background in computer science :-) But yes, if a function is just a relation, which is just a set, then such information is not really available.

Comment: @user118967 If one interprets "interpretation" (sorry for pun) as something like an indexed family of functions (cf. @ derek elkins's answer below) then I think your interpretation is still at least partially correct. Specifically, if you consider the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ to be part of the formal language signature $\sigma$, then the interpretation $I$ has to send those (object theory) quantifiers to new quantifiers in the metatheory (where $\mathbb{N}$ is defined) basically corresponding to quantification restricted to that "domain" $A$ ($\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Also even restricting the part of $I$ that is a map from relation symbols in the object theory to relation symbols in the metatheory, $\emptyset$ is not "an empty set", but instead a symbol/formula in the metatheory. I.e. so even considering that part of $I$ as a binary relation i.e. subset of the cartesian product of "object theory language relation symbols" $\times$ "metatheory language relation symbols", the corresponding subset of "metatheory relation symbols" is not empty, instead it's something more like $\{\emptyset\}$. So I think that you're right and that this is not a counterexample.

Comment: In my example, $\emptyset$ denotes the empty set in the metatheory: it is not a symbol or a formula but a value. If you use the usual set-theoretic view of functions, then you can't recover the domain or signature of a structure from an interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term "interpretation *function*" might be misleading you a bit.  It's really better to think of a family of interpretation functions indexed by arity and whether they are interpreting function symbols or relation symbols.  We just use the same symbol for all of these as an abuse of notation.  We could write $I_r^n : \{ s \in \sigma\ |\ \text{ar}(s) = n\text{ and } s\text{ is a relation}\}\to 2^{A^n}$ and $I_f^n : \{ s \in \sigma\ |\ \text{ar}(s) = n\text{ and } s\text{ is a function}\}\to A^{A^n}$ which get lifted to arbitrary terms and expressions compositionally.  While we could say the elements of $\sigma$ are essentially triples from a set like $\{r,f\}\times\mathbb{N}\times|\sigma|$ and thus write $I : \{r,f\}\times\mathbb{N}\times|\sigma|\to\ ?$ but it's not clear what to put in the codomain short of unioning together a bunch of function and relation types.  If we capture the connection between the domain and codomain we get a family (essentially a dependently typed function).

From the categorical perspective of [Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory), the interpretation function is represented by a (finite-product preserving) functor from a category that essentially represents the signature.  From this perspective (which doesn't immediately handle relation symbols, but that's an easy generalization), $I$ is a functor, $I : \sigma \to \mathbf{Set}$, such that $I(1) = A$, where $1$ here just represents an object of $\sigma$ and $n$ is an $n$-fold product of $1$.  Now since $I$ preserves finite products, $I(n) = A^n$.  A function symbol, $\mathtt{f}$, with arity $n$ is represented by an arrow $\mathtt{f} : n \to 1$ in $\sigma$.  Then the normal action of functors on arrows takes $\mathtt{f}$ to $I(\mathtt{f}) : A^n \to A$. (Actually, for technical reasons usually the opposite category of $\sigma$ is used so $n$ becomes the $n$-fold *co*product of $1$ which makes more sense notationally.)